# how to close two form but just using single command(SetVisible), Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I have two forms form1 and form2. I want when i `setVisible(false)`  form1, then form2 also automatically `setVisible(false)`. So, how to use a single command setVisible but immediately close two forms.

Or maybe how to make form2 be like confirmdialog. so, do not get into Form1, if form2 has not closed

How can i do it?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just check if form1 `isVisible(form1)` and if so, just `setVisible(false)`.
Is this what you want?

And another thing comes in my mind. Depends what you want to do, maybe use `dispose()` instead of `setVisible()`.

Hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Write a method for this and use it instead:

```
private void setFormsVisible(boolean b) {
  form1.setVisible(b);
  form2.setVisible(b);
}
```

You forms should be class-variables then. You could also try to make the forms final, and override the setVisible-method of form1.

Answer (score 0):

form2 should be a modal dialog with the parent set to form1. This will prevent interaction with form1 until form2 is closed.